# How to filter only values with type Symbol in an array?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm working on [arrow library](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow) where I'm creating a function that returns only elements with type `Symbol`.

I use the `filter` function on an array :

```
export const extractSymbol = array => {
    if (isArray(array)) {
        return array.filter(value => typeof value === "symbol")
    }
}
```

But because I'm creating tests before the implementation, This test fail :

```
  expect(extractSymbol([1, 2, 4, Symbol('vue'), Symbol('react')])).toStrictEqual([Symbol('vue'), Symbol('react')]);
```

I expected true but it returns :

```
 Expected: [Symbol(vue), Symbol(react)]
 Received: serializes to the same string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two symbols created with the same parameter are not equal to each other:

```js
console.log(
  Symbol('foo') === Symbol('foo')
);
```

For the test to work properly, define the symbols outside the `expect`, so you can pass the same reference to both arrays:

```
const s1 = Symbol('vue');
const s2 = Symbol('react');
expect(extractSymbol([1, 2, 4, s1, s2])).toStrictEqual([s1, s2]);
```

Comment: Tests passed bu may I know what's the difference between the creation in an array and outside an array, and what happened exactly?

Comment: With `[Symbol('vue')], [Symbol('vue')]`, you've called `Symbol` twice, so the symbols are separate (not equal to each other). But with `const s = Symbol('vue'); compare([s], [s])` you've called `Symbol` only once, so the one symbol created is equal to itself.

Comment: A way of looking at it is, it's a bit like objects: `{} !== {}`, but `const obj = {}; obj === obj`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let arr = [Symbol('foo'), 123];

let filtered = arr.filter(x => typeof(x) == 'symbol');
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, tests failed but what's the difference between `typeof` with `()` and without them ?

Comment: typeof 'example' and typeof('example') are both valid syntax

Comment: But the problem was not related to syntax.

Comment: i mean you can write typeof with or without parenthesis